# Instagram API count limits using HTTP header

Tags: php, http-headers, instagram

According to Instagram you can check API limit count remaining using the HTTP headers that they supply with the call. I am quite new to this and am unable to find relevant data on how to access this information with PHP. Could anyone please clarify this for me?

I found the following from the Instagram API developers forum on Google Groups:

> *"We just rolled this out to production; all API calls now have the
>   additional HTTP headers:*
>
> - *`X-Ratelimit-Limit` (total # of possible calls per hour)*
> - *`X-Ratelimit-Remaining` (how many calls are left for this particular token or client ID)"*

Comment: `u`? please... if you're in such a rush that you can't afford the extra 0.01 seconds it takes to add in the `yo`, then perhaps you should try somewhere else.

Comment: ^^ sorry its a bad bad, habit i picked up from chatting , wouldn't happen again :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using [`file_get_contents`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to make the request (or anything that uses the [HTTP wrapper](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) for that matter), the special variable [`$http_response_header`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) contains an array of lines with the HTTP response headers of the most recent request.

Maybe something like this:

```
// Make your API request here
...
file_get_contents('http://example.com', false, $context);

// Check HTTP response headers
foreach ($http_response_header as $line) {
    if(preg_match('!X-Ratelimit-Remaining: ([0-9]+)!i', $line, $matches)) {
        $remaining = $matches[1];
        break;
    }
}

// Do something based on the number of remaining attempts
echo "Remaining attempts: $remaining";
```

Comment: ^^ yes that dose work just tried and where i was using curl post and used var_dump(get_headers('url that i used to make the call',0)) and i was able to see the ratelimit of overall api calls which they have set ass 5000 , i thought they would supply rate limitation details for relationship modifications too, which they have as 160 modification for an hour , which is BS :D hehe, anyways thanks for the help. marked as answerd.